# AngularJs - access scope variable in ng-repeat with same name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

trying to access controller variable in ng-repeat with same name.
e.g.

**Controller**

```
$scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];

$scope.a = {
  data: "Some Data"
};
```

**View**

```
<div ng-repeat="a in items"> {{ a }} - {{ $parent.a.data }} </div>
```

but it is not working. is it possible to access that variable (Object) inside ng-repeat with same name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to make it, is accessing variables by naming your controller (Some example [here in doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example)).

You can name your controller like `ng-controller="TestCtrl as ctrl"`

Then, you need some changes in your **view** :

`<div ng-repeat="a in ctrl.items"> {{ a }} - {{ ctrl.a.data }} </div>`

And in your **controller** :

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = [1,2,3,4,5]; //brackets here, not curly brackets as said by @georgeawg 
    self.a = {
        data: "Some Data"
    };

    // Rest of you code
});
```

Finally, naming controllers is quite a good practice.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

If you intend `$scope.items` to be an array, use square brackets, not curly brackets.

```
//Do THIS
$scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
//NOT THIS
$scope.items = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Your `ng-repeat` iterator can be anything. There is no need to overload a parent scope variable.

```
<div ng-repeat="anything in items"> {{ anything }} - {{ a.data }} </div>
```

Also if the parent variable is not overloaded, there is no need to use `$parent`.

The variables in elements repeated by `ng-repeat` prototypically inherit from the parent scope. For more information, see [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)